# React-Router browser back button doesnt work properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When i go from /xpage to xpage/detail/:id and then when i click browser back button it redirects me to two previous pages. How can i solve that?

```
<Route path="/xpage" element={<xPage />} />
<Route path="/xpage/detail/:id" element={<xDetail />} />
```

I redirect from /xpage to xpage/detail/:id via

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate("xpage/detail/1")
```

When i click the back button i expect it to redirect me to previous therefore /xpage page

Comment: How are you navigating from `"/xpage"` to `"/xpage/detail/:id"`? So you navigate from *somewhere* to `"/xpage"`, then navigate to `"/xpage/detail/:id"`, then click the browser's back button and navigate back to the "somewhere"? Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] and better reproduction steps with expected vs observed behavior results.

Comment: That seems unverifiable/unreproducible from the code you've provided. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score -1):

1. wrap your **xDetail** route inside **xPage**.
2. make sure have imported `<Outlet />` from react-router-dom in xPage.

it should be like

```
<Route path="/xpage" element={<xPage />}>
    <Route path="/xpage/detail/:id" element={<xDetail />} />
</Route>
```

xPage code should be

```
// all imports
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const xPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {/* code */}
            <Outlet />
        </>
    )
}
export default xPage
```

Comment: Nesting the routes doesn't fundamentally change how they are navigated to.